# update concat value to a single column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to update the concat value to a single column. Please help me to update this.

```
update tbl_data1 
   set FLD_REMARKS= 
       (select i.fld_id||':'||i.fld_calc_id||':'||0||':'||0 
          from tbl_cust_order p, tbl_cust_bill i 
         where i.fld_item_id=p.fld_id 
           and p.fld_item_id=110 
           and rownum =1 
         order by p.fld_id desc)
 where fld_id=243078
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what the problem is, but maybe this will help:

```
update tbl_data1 
   set FLD_REMARKS= 
     (select TheFld FROM (
       (select i.fld_id||':'||i.fld_calc_id||':'||0||':'||0 TheFld
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.fld_id desc) rn 
          from tbl_cust_order p, tbl_cust_bill i 
         where i.fld_item_id=p.fld_id 
           and p.fld_item_id=110)
         WHERE rn = 1)
 where fld_id=243078
```